# Error executing an HTTP request in kaggle

Tags: python, python-3.x

when i run this code

```
nq_task = t5.data.TaskRegistry.get("nq_context_free")
ds = nq_task.get_dataset(split="validation", sequence_length={"inputs": 128, "targets": 32})
print("A few preprocessed validation examples...")
for ex in tfds.as_numpy(ds.take(5)):
  print(ex)
```

i have this error

```
PermissionDeniedError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details></Error>'
     when reading gs://t5_abstr_summ_arxiv_001/train1.tsv
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve? ]What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Please provide full code. As the error suggests you are not authorized to access the google cloud storage object so look into that